# Script selenium python always detected as bot on flashseats :(

Tags: php, python, selenium, web-scraping, detection

my script always detected why ?!!!!
most of time i use python selenium for scraping website but this time i'am always detected by "https://www.flashseats.com"

Can you help me please!!

here's part of my selenium code , i even try to use different proxies but :( same result, 
please propose me a solution either in python or PHP.

```
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
        options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
        options.add_argument('--incognito')
        options.add_argument('--disable-plugins-discovery')
        options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

        #_chrome_options = Options()
        #_chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\browser\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)

        time.sleep(10)


        driver.get("https://www.flashseats.com/")
```

Comment: it's trivial to detect webdriver is being used..  also, when a site uses decent bot detection, there is a good chance your scraping violates the site's TOS.  you should probably stop scraping it.

Comment: ummmm, but i think that there's some people doing it ? 
Thanks Corey Goldgerb